# How to disable submit button of form on page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to disable submit button when page loads and after finishing the loading of page it becomes active can anyone help me how to do that

```
<form>
   Firstname:
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this once

```
<form>
   Firstname:
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').attr('disabled',false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will enable all buttons on the page

Comment: @mplungjan OP didn't say he have multiple buttons on the page.

Comment: Why not a second time?

Comment: @Peter He likely meant, "Why don't you try this"

Answer (score 5):

Disable the button in HTML and give it an ID - this is assuming you do not need to support browsers with JavaScript disabled.

```
<form>
   Firstname:
   <input type="text">
   <button id="subbut" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you can do

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
  $("#subbut").attr("disabled",false); // or removeAttr("disabled")
});
```

**Plain JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("subbut").disabled=false; // or removeAttribute("disabled")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
   Firstname:
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and then in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('button').attr('disabled',false);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `disabled="disabled"` attribute to your button and this script:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
  });
</script>
```

After the page is loaded the ready event will be fired and the disabled button becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button as disabled

```
<button id="myButton" type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

and on document ready, enable it using below code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Please format your code and show HOW to enable the button

Answer (score -3):

Step 1:

Inside init method in c#, you can disable the button by applying css dynamically.

```
controlname.attributes.add("disabled","disable");
```

Step 2:

Inside pageload, at the end of method, you can enable the button again by applying css dynamically.

```
controlname.attributes.add("disabled","enable");
```

Comment: There's no C# on the tags above, Please read the question carefully before answering